# Is it possible to add a timestamp for the target folder with httrack?

Tags: httrack

I am using httrack to backup my websites via command line:

```
httrack https://www.example.com  -O "websites/example.com"  -%v
```

Is it possible to add a timestamp to the target folder to get a target folder like this:

```
websites/example.com-2019-07-18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following command:

```
httrack https://www.example.com  -O "websites/example.com-$(date '+%F')"  -%v
```

For more examples look at `man date`.